# Magento2 and Docker-Compose is incredible slow on Linux

Tags: magento2, docker

We are working on a local env for developers and a Magento 2 Docker-Compose Stack.

We are using nginx, PHP 7.2, Elasticsearch and Varnish.

However, we experience unbearable loading times with and without xDebug enabled.

A bigger Magento 1 Codebase works fine with a similar setup.

I've found out that it does not matter if I let every service has its own mount to a directory or if I inbound it via `volumes_from` command...